# jquery hover in and out

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseleave, mouseenter

I have 4 boxes within a list. I am trying to set the width to 100% on hover. It works well without setting float:left to the li elements. When float:left is set, the hover over the box on the right flickers on hovering.

The code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/PsYn9/5/

If I hover over box #2, there is flickering. Why does this happen

Comment: This i sa bit of a design problem. The problem is that when the hover happens the box moves away from the cursor, so it's natural that it'll flicker.

Answer (score 4):

When the li gets stretched, it's not overlapping the other li, but making room for itself by *pushing* it. So when you hover over an li on the second column, it itself gets pushed, so you aren't hovering over it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Because onhover the div is stretched to 100% it results in starting below div1. That results in a mouseout, because the mouse isn't hovering on the div...

Answer (score 0):

When you put mouse over that box mouseenter is triggered and width is set 100% and box goes below, so mouse in not over it anymore and mouseleave is triggered so width is set to 48% and box goes on previous position where is still mousecursor, so mouseenter is triggered and width is set 100% and box goes below ...

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is normal. It happens because when you hover over the second box the box doesnt fit on the container so it drops to the second row (so float works this way). And when the box drops to the second row is like you stop hover on it so it returns to its original size and position. Then its again on its place and you are hovering over it againg, and so on... This is why its flickering.

Solution:
Make the container wider and work with fixed withs for the boxes.